# The public key of the certificate doesn't match the public key of the private key when usign PHP to create them

Tags: php, openssl

Good afternoon.
Until now I myself generated certificates to interact with web services using OpenSSL in the following way:

```
openssl genrsa -out private_key.key 2048

openssl req -new -sha256 -key private_key.key -subj "/C=AR/O=Organization Name/CN=Common Name/serialNumber=CUIT 999999999999999" -out certificate.csr

openssl pkcs12 -export -in certificate.crt -inkey private_key.key -out certificate.p12 (*)
```

(*) I do the latter when I get the certificate.crt file from the certificate.csr file on the web service owner's web page.web service owner's web page.

While this methodology works well for me I wanted to go a bit further and start doing this with PHP.
After some research I came up with the following code:

```
<?php
// Create private key
$privateKey = openssl_pkey_new(
    array(
        'private_key_bits' => 2048,
        'private_key_type' => OPENSSL_KEYTYPE_RSA,
    )
);
openssl_pkey_export_to_file($privateKey, dirname(__FILE__) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'private_key.key');

// Create certificate
$dn = array(
    "countryName" => "AR",
    "organizationName" => "Organization Name",
    "commonName" => "Common Name",
    "serialNumber" => "CUIT 99999999999"
);
$csr = openssl_csr_new(
    $dn,
    $privateKey,
    array('digest_alg' => 'sha256')
);
openssl_csr_export_to_file($csr, dirname(__FILE__) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'certificate.csr');

// Free private key
openssl_free_key($privateKey);
```

When I run it, it generates the private_key.key and certificate.csr files.
The problem I have is that doing this from PHP the public key of the certificate.csr file does not match the public key obtained from the private_key.key file; while if I do it with OpenSSL it does match.
If I try to generate the p12 file with OpenSSL from the files generated with PHP and the CRT file downloaded from the web service owner's website:

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -in certificate.crt -inkey private_key.key -out certificate.p12
```

I get the error "No certificate matches private key".
I seem to be generating the certificate.csr file in the wrong way but I can't find where I'm going wrong.
Can someone help me?

Comment: Your workflow is fine. Either you've mixed up the certificate file, or whoever is signing the certificate is messing something up. Run `openssl req -noout -modulus -in certificate.csr` and `openssl rsa -noout -modulus -in private_key.key` and you should see that the moduli match. Past that point it's up to the CA to not drop the ball during signing. `openssl x509 -noout -modulus -in your_cert_file` is the equivalent command for the signed certificate.

Comment: I rechecked everything and indeed there must be something wrong with the script that generates the files. The script I showed in the query is a reduced version with fixed data. The files generated with that version match, while the full version does not (I ran `openssl req -noout -modulus -in certificate.csr` and `openssl rsa -noout -modulus -in private_key.key` for the pair of files generated with both scripts), so I will check carefully what is different in the full script. Thanks @Sammitch!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reviewing the code carefully and not finding anything out of place I proceeded to completely rewrite it without looking at the previous version and simplifying everything as much as possible.
Finally it worked, the only suspicion I have is with the private key, I generated it in a script and then read it from another one to generate the CSR.
Cheers.